# Reset a base elevation in Pix4D?

Tags: lidar, elevation, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, dem, pix4d

Does anyone know how to set a baseline elevation in Pix4D, or is that something that has to happen on the drone-capturing side?

The reason is that I have an area which is flown with LiDAR, several years have passed and now I want to measure the growth of the vegetation. However, I know the bare-earth baseline elevation for the take-off point, but the GPS vertical on the UAV is not that accurate, so if it is recording elevation with each picture that elevation may be relatively accurate for that flight, but could be ~5-10m off the baseline. If I could systematically adjust all elevations on the pictures by the same amount the drone is out from the bare earth DEM at the takeoff point then I would have a (hopefully) more accurate measurement of the difference between the LiDAR DSM and the UAV flown DSM.

Anyone know if that should happen when the UAV is set to fly, or if it is something that I can adjust in Pix4D before the processing?

Answer (score 2):

You may go to the top-left toolbar and click:

```
Project > Image Properties Editor > To file
```

to export the initial GPS. Then, edit the values and come back to reimport the coordinates file.

```
Project > Image Properties Editor > From file
```

<sub>@AndreSilva:</sub>
Pix4D is a Swiss-based company who develops Pix4Dmapper, an image processing software that reconstructs the 3D as well as generates an orthorectified mosaic from the images.