# Setting elevation data for tie points in Pix4D

Tags: gps, elevation, photogrammetry, pix4d

I am currently working in Pix4D and am trying to assign elevation data to my selected tie points. I have aerial images taken using a camera with GPS from an aircraft and am working with a fairly rectangular, level area of interest (AOI). I want to set a base elevation for the AOI, and have selected 6 sets of tie points - 1 at each corner and then 2 on either sides. I will then be giving them all the same elevation.

I have carried out the processes as detailed in the following post - [Reset a base elevation in Pix4D?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169071/reset-a-base-elevation-in-pix4d) - but all I was given was the option to change the altitude of the what looks like the camera (which is in the aircraft).

Does anyone have any idea how to assign elevation data to tie points specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may click on some automatic tie point (the one you want to assign the elevation to), and then click: [image]

After clicking the correct position on more than 2 images, the coordinates will be displayed in the up-right. Change the point type from "manual tie points" to "3D GCP" and then change the elevation value.

Repeat this for 3 points, well-distributed on the entire region, and then re-optimize. Hope this works :)